# Issue with Nova-Cloud-Controller and Ceph-Mon with Openstack base bundle

Tags: juju

Openstack Base bundle Lab:

All virtual environment has been realised using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and so composed:

- 1 VM for Ubuntu MAAS (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB)upgraded with ppa stable;
- 1 VM for Ubuntu JUJU (memory: 8GB, CPU: 1, HDD: 500GB)upgraded with ppa stable;
- 4 VM for Ubuntu OPENSTACK (memory: 12GB, CPU: 2, HDD: 500GBx2);

At the end of the deploy of Openstack Base bundle via JUJU gui, I've received the following issue on Ceph-Mon and Nova-Cloud-Controller

[image]

here is Nova Cloud Controller

[image]

here is Ceph Mon

[image]
[image]

its own juju status is reported [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24536176/). I've tried to open the openstack-dashboard obtaining that

[image]

Any solution for Nova-Cloud-Controller and Ceph-Mon? thanks

Comment: You need to wait for all charms to be in 'ready' state. Meanwhile you can check what is happening in nova-cloud-controller/ceph-mon by inspecting the respective juju logs.

Comment: juju debug-log --include unit-nova-cloud-controller-0

Comment: the issue was not on bundle but on the configuration of network on VMware ESX in physical host. thanks for support

Comment: Good to hear you were able to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved that issue. it was an error on the configuration of the port channel on VMware ESX between the physical Host and the switch of core layer.

[image]